# flex/bison: '$' operand giving large/wrong chunks of text

Tags: bison, yacc

I'm not sure how to put this, as "addressing" seems to refer to the "%" operand and specification of lines/columns, which is not what I am looking for. I am trying to figure out how exactly the "$" symbol works. Also I do not know if these are operands or what they are, if you can tell me, please do, if not, avoid focusing on what I call them, and emphasize on telling me what "$" does.
I have this fairly long expression in bison:

```
for: KW_FOR S_PARENTHESIS_OPEN assignment S_SEMICOLON gen_ex S_SEMICOLON assignment S_PARENTHESIS_CLOSE command_block 
{
printf("condition: %s", $3);
};
```

(note that anything in capitals is a token corresponding directly to a word/symbol)
and the input is:

```
void myProgram ()
BEGIN
x = 1;
if( x < 3 ) x = 2;

if(x > 3) x = 3; else x = 2;

while (x < 2)
BEGIN
y = 2;
END

for ( x = 1; y < 3; z = 2)
BEGIN
z = 4;
END

END
```

I was expecting that the printf() would give me the `for` keyword if I asked for `$1`, but it actually starts from `y = 2` in the previous "while" loop, which I cannot figure out since it is out of the scope of the expression.

So, how exactly is this supposed to be deciding where the reference I am making is? And since we're at it, what is this called anyway?

**Edit:** I know I write $3, and that works. If I write $1 it doesn't work as expected. I am asking what these stuff are called, and how bison decides what is the first symbol, and thus why it gives me things from before the particular expression if I ask for $1. That's what I want to know, as well as how to properly refer to these things.

Comment: `$` is not an operand. `$3` in your production refers to `assignment`. `$1` refers to the first symbol in the right hand side, but it's unclear why you need to access the `for` keyword at all. There is no '`%` operand' here. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I do not really need to access for, it was a test to see what it would show, and I was very surprised it neither showed the first non-keyword symbol, neither the first symbol in general. `$3` works fine, but I'd like to know why `$1` doesn't work as I expect it too, and how can I even look up the "$" thing, what it's called. I know there is no '`%` operand' but when I looked up addresses as the most plausible naming, that's what I got as results. You're missing the point, I know I'm wrong, and trying to figure out what's called what, and how it works

Comment: You're missing the point. There is no '`%` operand' here, and your explanation of what you meant by it only adds to the confusion. What you need to do is to post the *actual problem* you are encountering. Not a whole lot of other stuff you encounted while trying to solve it. There's no reason why `$1` should provide you with the text of a keyword unless you've programmed everything that way, *if* that's what you're expecting, which isn't clear, and if that's what you really need, which it isn't.

Comment: I only mentioned the "% operand" to indicate that if I look for "addresses" that's what I get in the results. I do not care about that symbol, and that's why it's not in my code. Now, If I want to check that "for" keyword, that's my business, and my mental problem. Assume that I really want to tamper with it if it helps. I believe it is clear that I am wondering why I don't get that "for" printed, but I get things that are outside of the expression.

Comment: I am doing my best to narrow down the problem with edits, specifying what I care about and what not.

Comment: If you want the `for` keyword, or indeed any keyword, as text, you have to arrange a production for it that copies `yytext` to `$$`. But it's pointless. You already know that it's `for`. It can't be anything else. Adding extra code to tell you what you already know would be a complete waste of time and space. It remains unclear what your actual problem is, or what you're actually asking. Instead of printing `$1`, just print `"for"`. Couldn't be more trivial.

Comment: Ok, that was bit more helpful, I'll try and rephrase it, regardless of if it's `for`, or what it is, why doesn't `for` appear when I put `$1`? Think completely low-level, bison doesn't know that it's useless, shouldn't it just print the first thing in the expression? Why does it print stuff from a previous expression?

Comment: I mean, I don't wanna print "for", I just want to know what to expect, how this works. I try printing "for" in this way so I can check that it goes as expected, because I am sure of what it should be printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$n` refers to the *semantic value* of the *n*<sup>th</sup> symbol on the right-hand side of the current production.

The semantic value of a terminal is whatever is assigned to `yylval` by the scanner rule which returned the terminal code. If the flex action does not assign anything to `yylval`, there is no semantic value (or, more accurately, the semantic value is uninitialized and it is *undefined behaviour*  to refer to it).

The semantic value of a non-terminal is whatever is assigned to `$$` by the parser (bison) action. If there is no action associated with a production, or if the action does not assign anything to `$$`, then the semantic value of the non-terminal is copied from `$1` (in that production). In that case, if `$1` has no semantic value, then neither does the corresponding non-terminal and again it is *undefined behaviour*  to attempt to use that value.

The (C) type of a semantic value is `YYSTYPE`, by default `int`, which you can set in your prologue. Or you can define it as a *union type* -- that is, a normal C `union` -- in which case, bison needs to know which union member applies to every terminal and non-terminal. In that case, the scanner needs to assign to the correct member of `yylval`.

I strongly suggest you read the [bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html). You could skip to the section on [semantics](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantics), but if you are just starting out, you'll find it useful to read from the beginning, paying particular attention to the examples.

Good luck.

---

A quick suggestion: don't fill up your grammar with things like `S_PARENTHESIS_OPEN`. That does not assist readability or efficiency or anything. Better style is to use *single-quoted* characters for single-character tokens, and to define *double-quoted* aliases for longer tokens:

```
 /* It is not necessary to declare single-quoted character tokens */
%token KW_FOR "for"
%%
 /* Example: */
for: "for" '(' assignment ';' gen_ex ';'  assignment ')' command_block
```

In your scanner, you return the actual character for single-character tokens; the longer tokens need to use the symbolic name declared in your `%token` line:

```
"for"     { return KW_FOR; }
[();]     { return yytext[0]; }
```

The second flex rule above spells out the possible single-character tokens, but it's even easier to use a fallback rule at the end of your flex rules:

```
.          { return yytext[0]; }
```

since any characters which don't correspond to single-quoted tokens in your bison specification will trigger a syntax error in the parser.

Comment: That was excellent, I modified the code to do `yylval = yytext;` for anything non-numerical and it works as expected! Thank you very much! I only have one small issue, if I print it as a string, it continues printing all the way to the end of the program, is there any standard way of dealing with this or should I devise some scheme to insert a `\0` at key points?

Comment: @user3079666: `yylval = yytext` is never correct. The string pointed to by `yytext` belongs to the scanner, and the scanner can and will modify it. You can only rely on the value for the duration of the flex action; by the time `yylval` has been passed to bison, the string will probably be modified (as you see). If you need to preserve the string value, you need to `strdup(yytext)` (or the equivalent), and to avoid a memory leak you need to `free()` the duplicated string when you don't need it any more. That's a lot of work, which is why keywords are not usually saved as strings....

Comment: @user3079666: Of course, given that you know the string value of the token, you could use a flex rule like `"for" { yylval = "for"; }` which sets `yylval` to the address of a constant string literal. But really you should ask yourself if you really need a keyword to have a semantic value. It's very very rarely useful, and if you want to debug your parser you are much better off using the bison trace facility (see the manual for details).

Comment: I could use `strcpy` though to copy it, right? For now I need to copy the contents of a `for` loop to do loop unrolling, if that helps put it into context, so I get the desired starting point and I only need to limit how far it goes, the whole `for` fuss was a point of reference, to see if the way I coded was calibrated correctly, metaphorically speaking.

Comment: @user3079666: As I said, "you need to `strdup(yytext)` (or the equivalent)..."; obviously, you could do `yylval = malloc(yyleng + 1); strcpy(yylval, yytext);` (or even `memcpy`). But why bother? You know what the string is. If you need a "point of reference" *use the bison trace facility*.